# What's the easiest way to revoke a PGP key using MacOSX?

Tags: macos, gnupg, pgp

I haven't used PGP in ages and since then I most likely lost the keys. I want to revoke them regardless and I do have the revocation keys printed in paper. I already typed and proof-read them a couple of times, now what?

I tried just importing them as keys and after I got rid of checksum errors I get this error from http://pgp.mit.edu:

> Add failed: Malformed Key --- unexpected packet type and/or order of packets

I downloaded the GPGtools for MacOSX and downloaded my public keys, but it doesn't do anything when I try to import the revocations into it.

How should I revoke them?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in this case is probably using the command line. Here's what you need to get started:

1. A copy of the public key (from the key server, for example) saved to a file, let's say `key.pub`
2. A copy of the revocation certificate, saved to a file, let's say `revoke.txt`
3. Some form of `gpg`. If you have installed GPGtools, you should be set to go.

## First: import the public key into your keyring

```
$ gpg --import key.pub
```

The computer says:

```
gpg: key 07F04249: public key "Not my key <test@example.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

If you want to check your work, you can list the keys that have been imported:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
```

The computer says:

```
/Users/blabbity/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------
pub   1024D/07F04249 2011-11-08
uid                  Not my key <test@example.com>
sub   2048g/82DDA00F 2011-11-08
```

## Second: import the revocation certificate

```
$ gpg --import revoke.txt
```

The computer says:

```
gpg: key 07F04249: "Not my key <test@example.com>" revocation
     certificate imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:    new key revocations: 1
```

Check your work again:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

The computer replies:

```
/Users/blabbity/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------
pub   1024D/07F04249 2011-11-08 [revoked: 2011-11-08]
uid                  Not my key <test@example.com>
```

## Finally: Upload the revoked key

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --send-keys 07F04249
```

Of course, replace `07F04249` with the id of your public key (which you can see in the output of the `list-keys` command).